# How to make the checkbox if checked will go to finished book in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi guys, I want to ask.

So, I have a submission to make a bookshelf app in website. Then one of the requirements is when you checked the "already finish" checkbox, it will be go to finished book, but if you don't checked it, it will go to unfinished book. But I confused how to make it.

Could you help me solve this problem ? Thank you

```js
const UNCOMPLETED_READ = "unfin-book";
const COMPLETERD_READ = "fin-book";


function resetalert() {
  alert("Data was reset");
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

  const submitForm = document.getElementById("addform");

  submitForm.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    addList();
  });
});
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const inputMinLengthOnLoad = document.getElementById("bookid").minLength;
});

document.getElementById("bookid").addEventListener("input", function() {
  const jumlahKarakterDiketik = document.getElementById("bookid").value.length;
  const jumlahKarakterMinimal = document.getElementById("bookid").minLength;
  console.log(jumlahKarakterDiketik, jumlahKarakterMinimal);
  const KarakterUpdate = 0 + jumlahKarakterDiketik;
  document.getElementById("MinAngka").innerText = KarakterUpdate;
  if (KarakterUpdate == 5) {
    document.getElementById("MinAngka").innerText = "Minimum number has reached";
  } else if (KarakterUpdate <= 4) {
    document.getElementById("notifikasiMinAngka").style.color = "red";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("notifikasiMinAngka").style.color = "black";
  }
});


function addList() {

  const UFBook = document.getElementById(UNCOMPLETED_READ);

  const textTitle = document.getElementById("booktitle").value;
  const textID = document.getElementById("bookid").value;
  const textAuthor = document.getElementById("bookauthor").value;
  const textYear = document.getElementById("bookyear").value;

  const todo = makeList(textTitle, textID, textAuthor, textYear, false);
  UFBook.append(todo);


}

function makeList(title, id, author, year, isFinish) {

  const textTitle = document.createElement("h3");
  textTitle.innerText = title;

  const textID = document.createElement("p");
  textID.innerHTML = 'Book ID : <span id="id">' + id + '</span>'

  const textAuthor = document.createElement("p");
  textAuthor.innerHTML = 'Author : <span id="author">' + author + '</span>'

  const textYear = document.createElement("p");
  textYear.innerHTML = 'Year : <span id="year">' + year + '</span>'

  const textContainer = document.createElement("div");
  textContainer.classList.add("inner")
  textContainer.append(textTitle, textID, textAuthor, textYear);

  const container = document.createElement("div");
  container.classList.add("item")
  container.append(textContainer);

  if (isFinish) {
    container.append(
      createUndoButton(),
      createDeleteButton()
    );
  } else {
    container.append(
      createDoneButton(),
      createDeleteButton()
    );
  }

  return container;
}

function toCompleted(taskElement) {
  const taskTitle = taskElement.querySelector("h3").innerText;

  const taskID = taskElement.querySelector("span#id").innerText;

  const taskAuthor = taskElement.querySelector("span#author").innerText;

  const taskYear = taskElement.querySelector("span#year").innerText;

  const finished = makeList(taskTitle, taskID, taskAuthor, taskYear, true);

  const toFinish = document.getElementById(COMPLETERD_READ);

  toFinish.append(finished);
  taskElement.remove();


}

function toRemove(taskElement) {
  taskElement.remove();
}


function toUndo(taskElement) {
  const Listunfinish = document.getElementById(UNCOMPLETED_READ);
  const taskTitle = taskElement.querySelector("h3").innerText;

  const taskID = taskElement.querySelector("span#id").innerText;

  const taskAuthor = taskElement.querySelector("span#author").innerText;

  const taskYear = taskElement.querySelector("span#year").innerText;

  const newBook = makeList(taskTitle, taskID, taskAuthor, taskYear, false);


  Listunfinish.append(newBook);
  taskElement.remove();

}


function createButton(buttonTypeClass, eventListener) {
  const button = document.createElement("button");
  button.classList.add(buttonTypeClass);
  button.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    eventListener(event);
  });
  return button;
}

function createDoneButton() {
  return createButton("done-button", function(event) {
    toCompleted(event.target.parentElement);
  });
}

function createUndoButton() {
  return createButton("undo-button", function(event) {
    toUndo(event.target.parentElement);
  });
}


function createDeleteButton() {
  return createButton("delete-button", function(event) {
    toRemove(event.target.parentElement);
  });
}
```

```css
/*Font */

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Quicksand:wght@600&display=swap');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/*Header*/

header {
  display: inline;
}

.jumbotron {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: #00c8eb;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

input {
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  max-width: 1800px;
  font-family: "Quicksand";
  font-size: 30px;
}


/*Navigasi*/

nav li {
  display: inline;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-right: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #00a2c6;
  padding: 9px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 3px solid red;
  color: white;
}

.nav-li a.active {
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 3px solid red;
  color: white;
}


/*Add book*/

.container-addbook {
  width: auto;
  height: 544px;
  margin-top: -35px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.container-search {
  width: auto;
  height: 244px;
  margin-top: -35px;
  background-color: red;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 40px;
}


/*Form*/

#addform {
  margin-left: 400px;
}

label {
  font-size: 20px;
}

#bookid {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 500px;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 107px;
}

#notifikasiMinAngka {
  margin-left: 187px;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}

#booktitle {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 500px;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 140px;
}

#bookauthor {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 500px;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 118px;
}

#bookyear {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 500px;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 138px;
}

.btn-submit {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  font-style: bold;
  width: fit-content;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-left: 220px;
  margin-top: 20px
}

.btn-reset {
  font-style: bold;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  width: fit-content;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 20px
}

#search {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 500px;
  margin-left: 410px;
  text-align: left;
}

.btn-search {
  font-style: bold;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  width: fit-content;
  padding: 5px 24px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: -10px
}

.container-unfinish {
  width: auto;
  height: fit-content;
  margin-top: -35px;
  background-color: green;
  padding: 30px;
}

.container-finish {
  width: auto;
  height: fit-content;
  margin-top: -25px;
  background-color: blue;
  height: fit-content;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 5px;
}

h3 {
  margin-top: -40px;
  font-size: 23px;
  margin-left: 190px;
  color: red;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

p {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 70px;
}

.container {
  width: 224px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: #F8F9FA;
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: fit-content;
}

.item {
  margin-left: 400px;
  width: 700px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.done-button {
  background: url('done.svg');
  background-size: contain;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 210px;
  margin-left: -300px;
  border: 5px solid #555;
  margin-right: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
}

.undo-button {
  background: url('undo.svg');
  background-size: contain;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 210px;
  margin-left: -300px;
  border: 5px solid #555;
  margin-right: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
}

.delete-button {
  background: url('delete.svg');
  background-size: contain;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 210px;
  margin-left: -300px;
  border: 5px solid #555;
  margin-right: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
}

input.cb {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-left: 182px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Digital Bookshelf</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Design.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Digital Bookshelf</h1>
  </div>

  <nav>
    <ul>
      <div class="nav-li">
        <li><a href="#add">Add book </a></li>
        <li><a href="#search">Search book</a></li>
        <li><a href="#unfinish">Unfinish book</a></li>
        <li><a href="#finish">Finish book </a></li>
        <li><a href="#profile">Profile</a></li>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <div class="container-addbook">
    <h2 id="add">Add book</h2>

    <form class="form" id="addform" name="form">

      <div class="form-group form-title">
        <label for="id">Book ID</label>
        <input type="number" id="bookid" name="bookid" placeholder="Book ID" minlength="5" required>
        <br>
        <label id="notifikasiMinAngka">Number inputed : <span id="MinAngka"></span></label>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="form-group form-title">
        <label for="title">Title</label>
        <input type="text" id="booktitle" name="booktitle" placeholder="Book Title" required>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="form-group form-title">
        <label for="author">Author</label>
        <input type="text" id="bookauthor" name="bookauthor" placeholder="Author" required>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="form-group form-title">
        <label for="year">Year</label>
        <input type="number" id="bookyear" name="bookyear" placeholder="Year" maxlength="4" required>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="form-group form-title">
        <input type="checkbox" id="inputBookIsComplete" name="already" class="cb">
        <label for="already">Already read</label>
      </div>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit" class="btn-submit">
      <input type="reset" value="Reset" name="Reset" onclick="resetalert()" class="btn-reset">

    </form>
  </div>

  <div class="container-search" data-aos="zoom-in">
    <h2>Search book</h2>
    <form id="searchbook">
      <input type="text" id="search" name="booksearch" placeholder="Search here">
      <input type="button" value="Search" name="searchnow" class="btn-search">
    </form>


  </div>

  <div class="container-unfinish" id="unfin">
    <h2>Unfinished book</h2>

    <div class="list-item" id="unfin-book">

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container-finish" id="fin">
    <h2>Finished book</h2>

    <div class="list-item" id="fin-book">

    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="Code.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask], especially the section titled "Help others reproduce the issue", where it mentions "If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on ... http://jsbin.com/) then do so - but also **copy the code into the question itself**. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time. Use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make a live demo of inline JavaScript / HTML / CSS."

Comment: Also see what is [mre] and why its important. Emphasis on minimal. Welcome to SO

Comment: @ikiK You should be careful when copying code from another site to this one on behalf of the OP, since you are relicensing their code under CC-by-SA, which may not be what they want.

Comment: Couldn't find the "Already Finish" checkbox the OP talks about.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Oh that never crossed my mind. But links are posted here publicly. But i get it. Thanks. What is done is done now.

Comment: Please create a reproducible example somewhere else as well. In this snippet we have to always scroll and it's difficult to comprehend the intention of the site as well. Also, please provide a step-by-step reproduction of the problem, explaining what was expected and what happened instead.